# query id not return a unique result: 6

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.1

I have this scenario:

MedidasController.java

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy/MM/dd")
    @GetMapping("/{unidade_id}/{dataInicial}/{dataFinal}")
    public Medidas listaMedidasPeriodo(@PathVariable("unidade_id") Integer unidade_id, @PathVariable("dataInicial") @DateTimeFormat(iso=ISO.DATE) Date dataInicial, @PathVariable("dataFinal") @DateTimeFormat(iso=ISO.DATE) Date dataFinal) {
        Medidas medidas = medidasRepositorio.listarMedidasPeriodo(unidade_id, dataInicial, dataFinal);
        return medidas;
    }
```

MedidasRepositorio.java

```
@Query(value="SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE unidade_id = :unidade_id AND (data_medicao >= :dataInicial AND data_medicao <= :dataFinal)  ORDER BY data_medicao,hora_do_dia ASC;", nativeQuery=true)
    Medidas listarMedidasPeriodo(@Param("unidade_id") Integer unidade_id,
                            @Param("dataInicial") Date dataInicial, 
                            @Param("dataFinal") Date dataFinal );
```

I got this error:
javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result: 6

What I am missing?
I

Comment: Maybe you want a method `List<Medidas> listarMedidasPeriodo(...)`?

Answer (score 1):

Add `LIMIT 1` to your query because there is more than one value returning from the query (if you want to retrieve one value)

, or add the return of the method to be `List<Medidas>` (if you want to retrieve all values)

```
   @Query(value="SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE unidade_id = :unidade_id AND (data_medicao >= :dataInicial AND data_medicao <= :dataFinal)  ORDER BY data_medicao,hora_do_dia ASC;", nativeQuery=true)
   List<Medidas> listarMedidasPeriodo(@Param("unidade_id") Integer unidade_id,
                            @Param("dataInicial") Date dataInicial, 
                            @Param("dataFinal") Date dataFinal );
```

Comment: Try to read in your spare time  here https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers